# automate updates with a bash script and cron

Tags: debian, email, cron, upgrade

I'm trying to automatize the updates of debian system, without making upgrades. Then i'll send an e-mail to me, everytime there is an upgrade available.

I've tryied to do it with cron-apt, but i really don't like how the configuration is organized, that's why i would prefer using a (cleaner) cron job that launch the script.

looking around i found that piece of code (not mein) :

```
if [[ `apt-get update 2>&1 | grep Get` ]]; then
  if [[ `apt-get --simulate dist-upgrade 2>&1 | grep Inst` ]]; then
    apt-get --simulate dist-upgrade
  fi
fi
```

From what i can understand, that script update the local packages list, and make a simulation of an eventual upgrade.

Now if it's possible i would like to send to me via email the output of the update, and of the upgrade-simulation. For acheave that i could use mail command:

sending first email:

> apt-get update | mail -s "daily update report" me@example.com

second email:

> apt-get --simulate dist-upgrade | mail -s "daily upgrade-simulation report" me@example.com

My main question is if there a better approach to do all this..?

Secondarely, I've tryied without succed to send everything in just one email, anybody know how i could do it?

Comment: `(apt-get update; apt-get --simulate dist-upgrade)|mail -s "foo" user@example.com` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel.

```
apt-get install apticron
```

> Apticron is a simple script which sends daily emails about pending package updates such as security updates, properly handling packages on hold both by dselect and aptitude.

Comment: thankyou for the answer! i didn't knew that package. I installed it and trying to configure the time when it checks and send email notification